# How to get group by group name in JSOM SP2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, jsom, groups

How to get group object from group name something like this.

```
var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
group = groupCollection.getByName("Group Name");
```

Above code will work in SP2013. But not in SP2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
var myGroupName = "Group Name";
var myGroup = null;

clientContext.load(groupCollection);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        var groupEnumerator = groupCollection.getEnumerator();
        while(groupEnumerator.moveNext()){
            var currentGroup = groupEnumerator.get_current();
            if (currentGroup.get_title() == myGroupName)
            {
                myGroup = currentGroup;
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

After this code runs, you should have the details of your group in the `myGroup` variable.